# Covert OME-TIFF to DZI using python

Tags: python, image, tiff, data-conversion

Basically a have an ome.tiff image file that cames from ImageJ, and i want to transform it in .dzi file. Currently i do: (ome.tff -> jpg -> dzi). But i want to transform directly in .dzi is that possible in python? and how?

I can't find anything related to this so I decided to ask here if anyone has any information about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read an OME-TIFF with [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/), and write a DZI file with [vips](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.html).

As both of these are Python, I guess there's a way of doing what you want, but you didn't share a representative input image so I cannot suggest much more.